# getSubimage throwing a NullPointerException for an unknown reason

Tags: java

Well, I'm trying to make a graphical game for the first time, but:

```
BufferedImage tileset = null;
try{
    tileset = ImageIO.read(new File("sets/tiles.png"));
}
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
MwatRoot.allTiles[0].tile = tileset.getSubimage(0, 0, 32, 32);
MwatRoot.allTiles[1].tile = tileset.getSubimage(0, 32, 32, 32);
```

this is throwing a NullPointerException:

```
MwatRoot.allTiles[0].tile = tileset.getSubimage(0, 0, 32, 32);
MwatRoot.allTiles[1].tile = tileset.getSubimage(0, 32, 32, 32);
```

this is allTiles:

```
public static TileClass[] allTiles = new TileClass[2];
```

and TileClass:

```
public class TileClass {
    public BufferedImage tile;
    public boolean BlocksMovement;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why that is happening? I already checked, tileset isn't null.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. However, using my ESP I'm going to guess that `MwatRoot` is `null` (If that's a static class, ignore comment. If not don't use uppercase for variable names), or `MwatRoot.allTiles[0]` or `MwatRoot.allTiles[1]` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static TileClass[] allTiles = new TileClass[2];
```

this does not correctly initialise the array.

You have to add after it, the following:

```
allTiles[0] = new TileClass();
allTiles[1] = new TileClass();
```

Comment: Oh, that was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Tarc: don't forget to both up-vote Adel's answer (as I have already done), and to also "accept" it by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.

Comment: @Tarc Please you have to mark this answer and accept it. Otherwise people will continue to answer here.

Comment: Ok, I just accepted it. Sorry but I won't be able to up-vote right now, my rep is still low.